# Explain why the correspondence $x \mapsto 3x$ from $\Bbb Z_{12}$ to $\Bbb Z_{10}$ is not a homomorphism.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

> Explain why the correspondence $x \mapsto 3x$ from $\Bbb Z_{12}$ to $\Bbb Z_{10}$ is not a homomorphism.

Here image of $1$ is $3$ and $|3| = 10 $ which does not divide $12$, the order of $1$. So this can't be homomorphism.

Is this correct?

Comment: In my previous comment, my notation/syntax was terrible - I'll fix things up in the answer section...

Comment: It's not even a well-defined map. It sends $1$ to $3$, but it sends $13$ (equivalent to $1$) to $39\equiv9$. And in $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$, $3\not\equiv9$.

Comment: Do you mean group homomorphism?

Answer (score 1):

This "map" is doomed from the outset, as it is not well defined.

As it fails to be a bonified function, it certainly can't be a homomorphism.

Besides, it is easy to see the only homomorphism, other than the trivial one, from $\Bbb Z_{12}$ to $\Bbb Z_{10}$ is $h$, given by $h(1)=5$.

Comment: This proof works only if the homomorphism is surjective.

Comment: Right.  But since $f(1)=3$, and $\langle3\rangle=\Bbb Z_{10}$, it is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your argument looks good.

Call your map $f$. On the one hand $f(0)= f(12\cdot 1)$. Therefore, for $f$ to be a homomorphism, one must also have 
$$ 0 = f( 0 ) = f(12\cdot 1) = 12 \cdot f(1) .$$
So (a factor of) $12$ would have to kill $f(1)$ in ${\mathbb Z}_{10}$  - but $f(1)=3$, and $$ 12 \cdot 3 = 6 \not= 0\in {\mathbb Z}_{10}.$$
So no factor of $12$ kills $f(1)$.